# Unique constraint on two database columns with reverse direction

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I'm stuck upon a following problem: Let's say I have a table with relations to itself:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (
    ID NUMBER(18) PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ITEM ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ITEM PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE TABLE ITEM_RELATION (
    FIRST_ITEM_ID NUMBER(18) NOT NULL,
    SECOND_ITEM_ID NUMBER(18) NOT NULL,
    RELATION_TYPE VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ITEM_RELATION ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ITEM_RELATION PRIMARY KEY (FIRST_ITEM_ID, SECOND_ITEM_ID, RELATION_TYPE);
--ALTER TABLE ITEM_RELATION ADD CONSTRAINT UK_ITEMS UNIQUE (FIRST_ITEM_ID, SECOND_ITEM_ID, RELATION_TYPE);
ALTER TABLE ITEM_RELATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FIRST_ITEM FOREIGN KEY (FIRST_ITEM_ID) REFERENCES ITEM(ID);
ALTER TABLE ITEM_RELATION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SECOND_ITEM FOREIGN KEY (SECOND_ITEM_ID) REFERENCES ITEM(ID);
```

Now let's say, I wan't the relation to be directional, that is if item 1 has relation to item 2 of certain type, the item 2 shouldn't have the same relation to item 1.

That is, the following should not be permitted:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Item 1');
INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'Item 2');
INSERT INTO ITEM_RELATION(FIRST_ITEM_ID, SECOND_ITEM_ID, RELATION_TYPE) VALUES (1, 2, 'R');
INSERT INTO ITEM_RELATION(FIRST_ITEM_ID, SECOND_ITEM_ID, RELATION_TYPE) VALUES (2, 1, 'R');
```

It means that the table `ITEM_RELATION` defines a direction of this connection, and it shouldn't be allowed to add a reversed relation.

Is it possible with Oracle DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a unique index.  In Oracle, you can use functions in indexes, so this will work:

```
create unique index unq_item_relation_3 on
     item_relation(RELATION_TYPE ,
                   least(FIRST_ITEM_ID, SECOND_ITEM_ID),
                   greatest(FIRST_ITEM_ID, SECOND_ITEM_ID)
                  );
```

You could get the same effect with a `check` constraint, by requiring that `FIRST_ITEM_ID` be less than `SECOND_ITEM_ID`:

```
alter table item_relation add constraint chk_item_relation_2
    check ((FIRST_ITEM_ID < SECOND_ITEM_ID);
```

However, this requires that the items be inserted in a particular order.

Comment: Thanks, that is perfectly what I wanted, the first solution works for me.